# The result is different.Why?

Tags: android, xml, search, sax, keyword

**This is code_1:**

```
public class SAXContenHandler extends DefaultHandler {

private Hotel hotel;
private String preTag = null;
private String keyWord;

public SAXContenHandler(String key){
    keyWord = key;
}
public SAXContenHandler(){

}

public void characters(char[] ch, int start,int length) throws SAXException{
    if(preTag != null){
        try{
            String chars = new String(ch,start,length);
            switch(preTag){
            case "hotel_id":
                hotel.setId(chars);
                break;
            case "name_tw":
                /*if(key == null)
                    hotel.setNameTw(chars);
                else*/
                    if(chars.indexOf("旅館")==-1) **<---------Here**
                        hotel = null;
                    else
                        hotel.setNameTw(chars);
                break;
            case "name_en":
                hotel.setNameEn(chars);
                break;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            //Log.d(TAG,"SAXContentHandler",e);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(localName.equals("hotel")){
        hotel = new Hotel();
    }
    preTag = localName;
}

@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(hotel != null){
        if(localName.equals("hotel")){
            hotels.add(hotel);
            hotel = null;
            //i++;
        }
    }
    preTag = null;
}
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

**And this is code_2:**

```
public class SAXContenHandler extends DefaultHandler {

private Hotel hotel;
private String preTag = null;
private String keyWord;

public SAXContenHandler(String key){
    keyWord = key;
}
public SAXContenHandler(){

}

public void characters(char[] ch, int start,int length) throws SAXException{
    if(preTag != null){
        try{
            String chars = new String(ch,start,length);
            switch(preTag){
            case "hotel_id":
                hotel.setId(chars);
                break;
            case "name_tw":
                /*if(key == null)
                    hotel.setNameTw(chars);
                else*/
                    if(chars.indexOf(keyWord)==-1)**<------HERE**
                        hotel = null;
                    else
                        hotel.setNameTw(chars);
                break;
            case "name_en":
                hotel.setNameEn(chars);
                break;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            //Log.d(TAG,"SAXContentHandler",e);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(localName.equals("hotel")){
        hotel = new Hotel();
    }
    preTag = localName;
}

@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(hotel != null){
        if(localName.equals("hotel")){
            hotels.add(hotel);
            hotel = null;
            //i++;
        }
    }
    preTag = null;
}
}
```

**Result:**

[image: Screenshot]

**situation 1:**

I use

`String key = "旅館";
SAXContenHandler handler = new SAXContenHandler(key);`

before use code_2.

**situation 2:**

I use

`SAXContenHandler handler = new SAXContenHandler();`

before use code_1.

---

When I use the method:`characters()` in situation1 and situation2, I think result should be the same.

BUT!!!!it's not.

What is the reason Why situation1 and situation2 is so different?

Oh! I forget to say: I want to use keyword to filter the xml data, but this is my first time to use xml file in android, so I'm not sure the idea in code is correct, or you can tell me correct idea, that will be helpful to me,thanks.

Comment: Looks like an encoding problem. Can you print the result you get in each case? (what is the value of `keyword` inside the `characters()` method?)

Comment: In code_1 I put "旅館" in method:`chars.indexOf()`, and in code_2 I type 旅館 in editText, and use `editText.getText()` to get text. It looks all the same between code_1 and code_2, but the result is so different..........

Comment: Post the code in which you are getting `editText.getText()`. I did a small test and it works perfectly. Show us your code so we can help better.

Comment: Sorry guys,I think I find mistake.........

I have two method one is `showXML()`, another is `showXML(key)`,but I didn't use `showXML(key)`,so the string didn't send to handler,guys thank for your help.